# Firebase Realtime Database Query: Filtering data based on the UserId signed in and a further unique identifier within the database

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query regarding an app I am trying to develop with node js react and Firebase Realtime Database.

The app is for a school and I am trying to write the correct code for filtering the data by course based on the course that the student has signed up for.

On the Firebase realtime database, I have two structure as per below:

```
- Courses
{
  "courseData" : [ {
    "course" : {
      "day" : "Tuesday",
      "duration" : "10 weeks",
      "language" : "German",
      "location" : "Online",
      "startdate" : "12th January",
      "term" : "January",
      "time" : "17.30-18.30",
      "timeofday" : "Evening",
    },
    "courseID" : "JRNGETNXXOLTUV",
    "dates" : {
      "class1" : "12/01/2021",
    }
}],
  "users" : {
    "kwvjUSgZKXXfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" : {
      "courseID" : "JRNGETNXXOLTUV",
      "email" : "test@test.com",
      "username" : "Test"
    },
    "vXf4WcRGQcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" : {
      "courseID" : "JRNGETNXXOLTUV",
      "email" : "test2@test.com",
      "username" : "Test Test"
```

I have a `courseID` in both `courseData` and the users section of the Firebase Realtime Database.

At the moment I can generate course data for a specific course when I manually insert the `courseID` as you will see below in the excerpt below.

Excerpt 1

```
filtercourse(courseID) {
  return function (coursedata) {
    return coursedata.courseID === courseID;
  };
}
```

....

Excerpt 2

```
<tbody>
{this.state.courseData.filter(this.filtercourse('JANSPADBGOLWEE')).map((data, index) => (
<tr key={index}>
```

...

Instead of manually inserting the courseID (in this case it's `JANSPADBGOLWEE`), I understand that I need to create a function where the `courseData` data is filtered by course/ courseID based on the `courseData.courseID` being equal to the `users.uid.courseID`, however, I this is beyond me it seems. Any help or advice here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you replace the schematic diagram of your database with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, many thanks for your response. I updated the original query as you requested. J

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a Firebase query, which allow you to [sort and filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries).

On `Courses`, you could get only its child nodes where `courseID` has a specific value with:

```
let courses = firebase.database().ref().child("courseData");
let courseSuery = courses.orderByChild("courseID").equalTo("JANSPADBGOLWEE");
courseSuery.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((courseSnapshot) => {
    console.log(courseSnapshot.key, courseSnapshot.child("course/day").val());
  });
});
```

---

If you first need to look up the course ID for the current user, that'd be:

```
let users = firebase.database().ref().child("users");
if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) throw "No current user";
let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
users.child(uid).once("value").then((userSnapshot) => {
  console.log(userSnapshot.val().courseID);
});
```

Note that this is a fairly standard way of loading data from Firebase, so I recommend reading some more of the documentation, and taking a few tutorials to get self-sufficient with it.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your reply. Apologies if I wasn't clear. The JANSPADBGOLWEE is the courseID which I manually inserted to show where I am at with the code. Is it possible to filter based on/ insert the courseID automatically based on the user who is signed in and the courseID that user was assigned in the Firebase Realtime database?  Thanks, J

Comment: I added some more of that, but (as also said in my answer) this is really quite standard Firebase fare - so I recommend reading some more to get self sufficient with it.

Comment: Understood, I will review the documentation further. Thanks for your help!